# Drupal 8 routing.yml not working?

Tags: drupal, module, controller, routes, yaml

I've just installed Drupal and got to working with it and this problem is keeping me from moving forward. After browsing through what feels like too many solutions, I still couldn't find a fix for this. I followed the steps in the Drupal site + many others in creating a custom module but ultimately end up with a "Page Not Found" landing page - the page still has Drupal's layout but it's not reading the controller I have set.

The structure of my folder:

```
drupal
   /modules
     /custom
       /sam
       sam.routing.yml
       sam.info.yml
       sam.module
       /src
          /Controller
          SamController.php
```

sam.routing.yml: (I'm kind of lost with this file, but I've been using spaces for indentation instead of tabs as I know yml files don't like tabs but I'm getting the feeling that Drupal isn't picking up on this routing.yml file. I did 2 spaces for the indentation)

```
sam:
  path: '/sam'
  defaults:
    _controller: 'Drupal\sam\Controller\SamController::build'
    _title: 'Sams Website'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

My controller:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\sam\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\ContainerInjectionInterface;

class SamController extends ControllerBase  {

   public function build() {
      return array(
        '#markup' => t('Hello World'),
      );
   }
}
```

I've checked the error logs in Apache and didn't really get any helpful messages. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

You need the initial `\` when specifying the fully qualified class name. Simply adjust your `routing.yml` to

```
sam:
  path: '/sam'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\sam\Controller\SamController::build'
    _title: 'Sams Website'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

Otherwise it will not build the route as the class cannot be found.